# In Grails 3 (3.2.6 confirmed), rendering view with null layout does not properly override default

Tags: grails, grails-controller, grails-3.0

In Grails 3, setting layout: null doesn't seem to override default layouts that may exist.  This wasn't the case in Grails 2.5.4.  The order of operations/precedence for overriding layouts appears to have changed.  Perhaps I'm using an undocumented feature by attempting to set render view: "myView.gsp", layout:null to avoid setting a layout?

```
   render view: "/account/profile/viewProfile",
                        layout: springSecurityService.isAjax(request) ? null : "customLayout"
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Grails 3 (confirmed w/ 3.2.6), if you have a layout that matches your controller name (i.e. AccountController and layouts.gsp) you have to change the layout to something else in order to control whether or not a layout is applied via the layout: null mechanism when rendering a view.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's covered in the documentation about setting a controller level default, and layout's being applied by (naming) convention.  But the change in behavior from Grails 2 to 3 to exclude layouts from being used by setting the layout to null while rendering a view, caught me by surprise and didn't seem to be covered in any migration guides I came across.